# Environment variable not setting up after running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, environment-variables

I am writing a bash script to automate the task of setting environment variables for my project. but when I execute my bash script using `sh env.sh` (env.sh is my file name). I am able to get value from the AWS secret manager and when I do echo inside the bash script I am able to print the env variable but when I run the echo $variable after the bash file is executed then it returns nothing.

I tried replacing eval to source but no luck

also i searched on stackoverflow for the issue but none of them helped.

find the script below

```
  #! /usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
 echo 'running'
 if ! [ -x "$(command -v aws)" ]; then
  echo 'Aws is not installed. Installing aws............................' >&2
  curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg" -o "AWSCLIV2.pkg"
  if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
   echo "The script need to be run as root." >&2
   exit 1
  fi
  sudo installer -pkg AWSCLIV2.pkg -target /
  if ! [ -x "$(command -v aws)" ]; then
   echo 'There was some issue installing aws cli. Install aws-cli manually and then run the script!!!' >&2
   exit 1
   fi
   echo "Running aws command please enter the aws access key and secrect"
   aws configure
  fi
   aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id abc --query SecretString --output text | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' > /tmp/secrets.env
   eval $(cat /tmp/secrets.env | sed 's/^/export /')
fi
```

I am currently running this bash file on Mac OS, but I would like it to operate on any OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file contained enviroment variable names `setup_local_env.sh`, Try

```
source setup_local_env.sh
```

This will add them to your current session.

There is another solution called *dot source*. Check the [reference here](https://ss64.com/osx/source.html)

```
. ./setup_local_env.sh
```

---

The reason if you directly run `./setup_local_env.sh`, it does not work, is because it creates a new bash process, and sets the environment variable there, and then it's lost once the new bash process exits.

Comment: And a downvote for answering the umpteenth dupe ..